# Create a graph from an adjacency matrix

Tags: java, adjacency-matrix

Im having trouble figuring out how to add an adjacency matrix file to a graph. 
im using the scanner and hasNextLine to go through the file, but cant figure out how to add the nodes and edges to my graph. Any help would be huge.

here is an example of a file that im taking input from:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UVt2.png)

Here is my graph class:

```
public class Graph {

    ArrayList<Node> nodeList;
    ArrayList<Edge> edgeList;

    public Graph() {
        nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        edgeList = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getNodeList() {
        return nodeList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> getEdgeList() {
        return edgeList;
    }

    public void addNode(Node n) {
        nodeList.add(n);
    }

    public void addEdge(Edge e) {
        edgeList.add(e);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "Graph g.\n";
        if (nodeList.size() > 0) {
            for (Node n : nodeList) {
                // Print node info
                String t = "\nNode " + n.getName() + ", abbrev " + n.getAbbrev() + ", value " + n.getVal() + "\n";
                s = s.concat(t);
            }
            s = s.concat("\n");
        }

        return s;
    }

}
```

And here is the class that i want to add the matrix from.

```
public class DelivB {

    File inputFile;
    File outputFile;
    PrintWriter output;
    Graph g;

    public DelivB(File in, Graph gr) {
        inputFile = in;
        g = gr;

        // Get output file name.
        String inputFileName = inputFile.toString();
        String baseFileName = inputFileName.substring(0, inputFileName.length() - 4); // Strip off ".txt"
        String outputFileName = baseFileName.concat("_out.txt");
        outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
        if (outputFile.exists()) { // For retests
            outputFile.delete();
        }

        try {
            output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            System.err.format("Exception: %s%n", x);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("DelivB:  To be implemented");

        // --------------------------------Deliverable B
        // -------------------------------------------//
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());

            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to parse each line of the input file. You should start by using `split()` to break the line into individual parts. Then you need to determine what each of those parts means.

Comment: You should take a step back from the code and think through what your final result needs to be. What do the nodes in your graph represent? What do the edges represent? How do you get the data for each of these from the file?

Comment: Write a small sample adjacency matrix and draw the graph you expect to be generated from it.